# How to compare two ctypes objects for equality?

Tags: python, ctypes

```
import ctypes as ct

class Point(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('x', ct.c_int),
        ('y', ct.c_int),
    ]

p1 = Point(10, 10)
p2 = Point(10, 10)

print p1 == p2 # => False
```

The equality operator '**==**' gives **False** in the trivial case above. Is there any straightforward approach?

EDIT:

Here's a slightly improved version (based on the accepted answer), which can also deal with nested arrays:

```
import ctypes as ct

class CtStruct(ct.Structure):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        for field in self._fields_:
            attr_name = field[0]
            a, b = getattr(self, attr_name), getattr(other, attr_name)
            is_array = isinstance(a, ct.Array)
            if is_array and a[:] != b[:] or not is_array and a != b:
                return False
        return True

    def __ne__(self, other):
        for field in self._fields_:
            attr_name = field[0]
            a, b = getattr(self, attr_name), getattr(other, attr_name)
            is_array = isinstance(a, ct.Array)
            if is_array and a[:] != b[:] or not is_array and a != b:
                return True
        return False

class Point(CtStruct):
    _fields_ = [
        ('x', ct.c_int),
        ('y', ct.c_int),
        ('arr', ct.c_int * 2),
    ]

p1 = Point(10, 20, (30, 40))
p2 = Point(10, 20, (30, 40))

print p1 == p2 # True
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a class MyCtStructure, then all its subclass don't need to implement `__eq__` & `__ne__`.
Defining eq wouldn't be a bit tedious job in your case anymore.

```
import ctypes as ct
class MyCtStructure(ct.Structure):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        for fld in self._fields_:
            if getattr(self, fld[0]) != getattr(other, fld[0]):
                return False
        return True

    def __ne__(self, other):
        for fld in self._fields_:
            if getattr(self, fld[0]) != getattr(other, fld[0]):
                return True
        return False

class Point(MyCtStructure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('x', ct.c_int),
        ('y', ct.c_int),
    ]


p1 = Point(10, 11)
p2 = Point(10, 11)

print p1 == p2
```

Comment: Yeah, that does the trick. Works nicely for nested structs. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`p1.x == p2.x and p1.y = p2.y` will work in this trivial case.

You could also implement the `__eq__()` an `__ne__()` methods in your `Point` class:

```
class Point(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('x', ct.c_int),
        ('y', ct.c_int),
    ]
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.x == other.x) and (self.y == other.y)
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

>>> p1 = Point(10, 10)
>>> p2 = Point(10, 10)
>>> p3 = Point(10, 66)
>>> p1 == p2
True
>>> p1 != p2
False
>>> p1 == p3
False
>>> p1 != p3
True
```

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly a correct approach. I forgot to mention that I'm looking for an approach that would be simple to use with complicated nested structs. Defining __eq__ would be a bit tedious job in my case...